# Sound problem Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on one of my laptop few months ago, however, after that, I constantly have sound problems.
For instance, one morning, when I turned on my laptop, there was no sound at all. However, when I followed this procedure
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Step 1c, then turn off my laptop, and turn on again, the sound is ok. 
However, after a while, the same problem emerged again, and for the last few months, it has been 6 times like this, I tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but the problem persists.
Can anyone help me?